# Get a header for a matrix in a certain order from another matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, header

I want to have a matrix with a header. I generate the matrix as follows

```
res.var <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
res.var <- as.data.frame(res.var)
```

I want to get the column names from another data frame in a certain order. I get the order of the column names from another data frame.

The column names are

```
column.names <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
column.names <- as.data.frame(column.names)
```

The order/postion is

```
position.vec <- c(3, 4, 5, 2)
position.vec <- as.data.frame(position.vec)
```

I try to connect the two matrices as follows:

```
j <- 1
l <- 4

while (j <= l) {
  names(res.var)[j] <- column.names[position.vec[j, 1], ]
  j <- j + 1
}
```

Anyone knows where my mistake is?

As a result I expect a table like this

```
resulting.table <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
resulting.table <- as.data.frame(resulting.table)
names(resulting.table) <- c("c", "d", "e", "b")
```

Also, is there there a way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setnames` to give names to `res.var` by extracting `column.names` according to `position.vec`

```
setNames(res.var, column.names[position.vec$position.vec,])

#   c  d  e  b
#1 NA NA NA NA
#2 NA NA NA NA
```

---

If we decide to keep `column.names` and `position.vec` as vector

```
res.var <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
res.var <- as.data.frame(res.var)
column.names <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
position.vec <- c(3, 4, 5, 2)
```

We can instead do

```
names(res.var) <- column.names[position.vec]
```

and if we want keep them as data frame we can do

```
names(res.var) <- column.names[position.vec$position.vec,]
```

Comment: Your first recommendation worked.
@Ralfino mentioned the second approach as well but I get an error message then: Error in `[.default(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: thanks. But I need the input `column.names` and the `position.vec` as data.frames

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following code to get rid of the loop and to get the values from the "a-e" range as column names. The nice thing is that you can just pass your "order vector" (`position.vec`) as indices to the column containing the header names.

```
res.var <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
res.var <- as.data.frame(res.var)

column.names <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
column.names <- as.data.frame(column.names)

position.vec <- c(3, 4, 5, 2)

names(res.var) <- column.names[position.vec,1]
```

If you also want/need the positions to come from a data.frame as well, then you need to change the last 2 lines in the code:

```
position.vec <- c(3, 4, 5, 2)
position.vec <- as.data.frame(position.vec)

names(res.var) <- column.names[position.vec[,1],1]
```

Comment: I tried that. I get the error message: Error in `[.default(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: For me it runs without error. If you run the script line by line, where does the error occur?

Comment: In the line where I write `names(res.var) <- column.names[position.vec, 1]`

Comment: Ah, I see. Note that in my code position.vec is not turned into a data.frame (I removed one line from your code). If it really has to be a data.frame you need to write: position.vec[,1] - which gives you the first column.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Should the code look like that then: `names(res.var) <- column.names[position.vec[, 1]]` ? Because that also gives me an error

Comment: Do you really need position.vec to be a dataframe? It increases the complexity without any benefit I can see in this case. However, if you want to keep it, go for this solution: `names(res.var) <- column.names[position.vec[,1],1]`

Comment: Thanks. I don't 'want' it. But I get it from the way of how I generate the table